# Update array's values from an inside function scope and then return them in Js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

In this *Filtered* **React.js** component, I am using the values of an array ("foofy") to apply into a return statement for filtering a `map()` method. The array should be populated by entries from a Firebase database, therefor the function above `filter()` and `map()`:

```
function Filtered () {
    let foofy = []
    alertMyAnsweredQuizzes()
    function alertMyAnsweredQuizzes () { 
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user !== null) {
            const userId = user.uid
            let ref = firebase.database().ref('users (uid)/'+ userId);
            ref.on("value", function(snapshot) { // it does not get out from here!
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    var key = childSnapshot.key;
                    foofy.push(key)
                }); 
                alert(foofy) 
                // foofy arrays should go outside into the return statement
                document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML += `==========`          
            })
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = `sign in to view your answered quizzes`
        }
   }
    return (
    list.filter((list) =>
        list.name == foofy[0] //should update by the function
        || list.name == foofy[1]
        || list.name == foofy[2]
        || list.name == foofy[3]
        || list.name == foofy[4]
        || list.name == foofy[5]
    ).map((list) =>
        <Link>
            {list.name}
        </Link>
    )  
    )

}
```

The thing is that I do not understand how can I get the updated array outside of its own function scope. Does anybody has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: `... list.filter((list) ...` Is it a list of list?

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to be setting `innerHTML` manually while using react. That is React's responsibility. Use conditional rendering or other methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, since a network request is made the code is asynchronous. So I would suggest having a loader to show when the data is fetched and then once the data arrives from Firebase you can remove the loader and show the data. An example implementation of the above might look like this,

```
function Filtered () {
    const [foofy, setFoofy] = React.useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

    alertMyAnsweredQuizzes()
    function alertMyAnsweredQuizzes () { 
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user !== null) {
            const userId = user.uid
            const ref = firebase.database().ref('users (uid)/'+ userId);
            ref.on("value", (snapshot) => { 
              const keys = [];
              snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                  var key = childSnapshot.key;
                  keys.push(key);
              }); 
              setFoofy(keys);
              setLoading(false);        
            })
        }
        else {
            // Code for login.
        }
   }

    if (loading) {
      return <h1>Loading....</h1>
    }

    return (
      foofy.filter((list) =>
        foofy.name == foofy[0] //should update by the function
        || foofy.name == foofy[1]
        || foofy.name == foofy[2]
        || foofy.name == foofy[3]
        || foofy.name == foofy[4]
        || foofy.name == foofy[5]
      ).map((list) => (
        <Link>
            {foofy.name}
        </Link>
      )  
    )
}
```